# Android framelayouts side by side

Tags: java, android, layout, android-framelayout

I would like to put two framelayouts side by side horizontally. My layout.xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.agodevs.vrcamera.MainActivity" >
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/camera_previewl" android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"></FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/camera_previewr" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I can only see one framelayout horizontally. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context="com.agodevs.vrcamera.MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_previewl"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ff0000" >
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_previewr"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#000" >
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Although personally I'd prefer reading it in terms of a weight which sums up to one, and thus giving each of them the value 0.5. In effect this achieves the same, given there is no weightSum provided.

Comment: It depends on us how we managed weight. I have keep in my mind with the ratio of 1:10

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA Why do you have problem having me here?

Comment: No i have not but i have need some help sometimes so

Comment: Tell me what help do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `FrameLayouts`, but you didn't specify their position. You can use `android:layout_toRightOf` property on the `camera_previewr` and point to `camera_previewl` as anchor. But `RelativeLayout` is not needed here if you just want to place 2 `Views` horizontally, use `LinearLayout` as root container instead with `android:orientation="horizontal"`

Comment: Note that the default orientation **is** horizontal, so there is no need specifying it, at least not in this case.

Comment: @Daneo yep, forgot it, the horizontal orientation is set to horizontal implicitly indeed.